# is variablize or variabilize a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

Is there a more appropriate word to use when ‘variablizing’ a data point (i.e to make something a variable) since the word variablize (or variabilize) does not seem to appear in the Oxford English Dictionary (yet), and it's a word people might use in certain contexts.

Comment: I don't understand.  If it's a data point, how do you make it variable?

Comment: I often use *parametrize*. I cannot think of a scenario where it would not do.

Comment: a parameter might be the boundary of a variable, but not exactly a variable. parametrize is a good one though...if parameter can get 'ized', variable should get 'ized' too. if it got 'ized' it would be able to see better too :)

Comment: when programming, a variable contains a value that can change dynamically. the end result can be the data point.

Comment: But to "make something variable" means to turn from a fixed value into one that changes value.  (What specific transformation are you doing on the data point?)

Comment: I don't like *variablize*, and I think that *parametrize* doesn't quite fit what you explained in the comments (which you should add to the question -- just hit the "edit" link), because the reader might think you want the data point to vary depending on the value of a parameter.  How about: "We will treat Point A as a variable parameter."  After you've made that clear, *then* you can talk about the parametrization you made.

Comment: here's a simple programming scenario. Variable X is a number. the fact that its a number, is a parameter of the variable. When a user uses the program to look up a value for X, the end result for the user would be the data point the user was looking to obtain.  The data set where possible X values are stored could be a table full of values, but the user sees only the value of X they are looking up.  basically, what we were discussing was to 'variabilize' the data set of values and display them to the end user . Everyone understood variablize, but its not an actual word.

Comment: That is as clear as mud.

Comment: so, trying making a point or explain the usage of a non-existent word  without success probably means that we should stop using it. anyone disagree?

Comment: The common expression is "assign to a variable", normally by type. For instance, "Assign the data set to an array of objects" covers your example. I don't think variablize would be understood, nor is it accurate. You're not converting data to a variable (named memory location), you're create a variable and assigning data to it.

Comment: @AviSaltzman The variable **is** a parameter to the lookup function. Without it, the lookup would be using a hard-coded value. By introducing the variable, you are parametrizing the lookup function. Or I don't understand your explanation (which is quite possible, as it's not entirely clear).

Comment: _By introducing the variable, you are parametrizing the lookup function._  I'm afraid I disagree with this...  the lookup function either accepts parameters or it doesn't -- using a variable as a parameter doesn't change that.

Comment: "Variabilize" isn't, as far as I know, a real word (been writing code for 35+) years, but, nonetheless, I would know exactly what you meant if you said it.  Words don't exist just to fit into rules, they exist to convey information/meaning.  If your users knew what you meant, go for it.  It serves its purpose, even if it is never used outside your situation.

Comment: I once was talking to some users and they kept trying to explain the problem they were having -- it happened whenever they did "eaky".  I had no clue what "eaky" was -- it certainly wasn't a part of the program I'd written.  Then I figured out they were saying "E-key" and meaning that they were using the menu option labelled "E".  I passed the word around to the other developers and from then on, that function was known as "eaky".  If everyone knows what you mean, it works. (I explored this a while back too: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sinasohn/lego-my-chess-set/posts/987444 )

Comment: For future visitors to this question, I found this because I just named one of my scripts "variabilize.awk" and wondered if it's a word (and if it was how you'd spell it). The context is simple: I have color definitions in a CSS file that appear in more than one place each, so this script passes the file over and replaces all instances of a string with another, intended to be a variable, so you can change all instances of the same color programmatically. So it is, in fact, turning data into variables, hence "variablizing" them. Hope this provides a bit more context.

Comment: So far as I can see from Avi's responses to Hot Licks' searching question, what seems to be happening is that a given 'data point' is being expanded into its constitutive data.  Is it that the term 'data point' is not a data point in the mathematical sense of a point on a graph.  But if it is not that, then in what sense is it a 'point'?

Comment: "Everyone understood ... but its not an actual word." That is actually the definition of a word. @AviSaltzman

Comment: To *abstract* is to replace a specific value with a construct that can provide a value. Although I feel there must be an alternative neologism like *abstractify* or *abstractualize* just because these are programmers not poets.

Answer (score 4):

***Variablize*** implies ***to make something into a variable***, but only makes immediate sense to software programmers.  Since it is not a dictionary word, it must be relegated to a [protologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protologism).

That being said, the closest word to your intended meaning is [***dynamize***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamize):

> 1:  to make (a drug) effective (as by comminution or dilution)
>
> 2:  to make dynamic:  endow with force

It is the second definition -- *to make dynamic* -- that most readily applies here.  If you make something static (i.e. a data point) into something dynamic (i.e. a variable) you ***dynamize*** it.

Of course, no one really uses ***dynamize*** in casual conversation either, even though it is in the dictionary.  Don't let that stop you from trying to make ***variablize*** into a [neologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism), though.

Comment: It more than implies, as that is essentially all we use -ize for.

Comment: It could be a prelogism.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context (computer science, data science), I'd use the word "[parameterize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parameterize)".

Comment: The link you provided spells the word differently than what you have in your post, the link spells it as "parameterize".

Comment: Thanks for the remark @DBADon. I fixed the misspell.

Comment: As a long-time programmer (in a few Western countries excluding the US) I can confirm that "parameterize" is in common use for this, and people mostly use "variablize" jokingly or when there is a useful semantic difference between "parameter" (a placeholder for function input) and "variable" (a more generic placeholder for any value).

Answer (score 1):

Two questions seem to emerge, one of which is about the English spelling of a verb  derived from Latin.  I shall leave the question of whether it is the right word for the particular use under discussion to people with better knowledge of the language of statistics than I have.

As to the spelling, first it seems that there is no help from academic dictionaries:  neither Merriam Webster UK not Cambridge English (Brit) recognises either.  But if there were such a word, or if it were to be coined among specialist terminology, there the guide is as follows.

Words (in fact, adjectives, though 'variable' is also a noun) ending in -able (such as 'liable') change to a noun by replacing '-le' with the noun ending '-ility.  So:

- *stable* ---> *stab**ility***
- *irritable* ---> *irritab**ility***
- *manageable* ---> *manageab**ility***  and, of course:
- *able* ---> *ability*

Just one warning, though.  US and British English part company over the final syllable of *visualise*.  US, unlike the British, has *visualize*.  Latin did not happen to have a letter *'z'*, though later Roman writers used this symbol to represent the Greek *zeta*, when translating Greek words into Latin.  So the Latin spelling with an 's' came down into British English via both scholarship and Britain's Norman conquerors.  The Americans went for the 'z' sound and spelled -*ize* and -*ization*.

Answer (score 0):

In the domain of statistics, you would create a *dummy variable* to handle data points that should be in one class or another.

If your domain is also statistics, instead of "variablizing" data points, please consider *Creating a dummy variable* for those data points.

Here is a quote from an answer on our sister site, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164583/2591), which is for statisticians.

> The inventor of dummy variables was George Boole in mid XIX century. On his book "An investigation of the laws of thought: on which are founded the mathematical theories of logic and probabilities" published on 1854 he proposes 0 and 1 as a mean to represent a class. You can look at his fascinating work on page 47 of his book on this link. http://www.archive.org/stream/investigationofl00boolrich#page/46/mode/2up

Here's a quote from the Wikipedia page on [Dummy Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)):

> Dummy variables are "proxy" variables or numeric stand-ins for qualitative facts in a regression model.

Answer (score 0):

In the fields of applied mathematics or mathematical  programming, you could use the term **variabilize** informally in explaining something at a whiteboard, just as you could use **constantize**, **functionize** or similar forms. For example, you might be assigning a different meaning to a symbol in an expression.  Your audience will almost certainly understand your intent.

However, this is one of those areas where informality can conceal your larger meaning.

For example, if your intent is to **relax a constraint** in your model, you are saying something about the external world you are seeking to represent.

If your intent is to **vary a parameter** to study a family of behaviors, or to plot a family of curves, you are implicitly giving the parameter less freedom of movement.

If you **make some quantity variable**, you are asserting your ability to vary it. If you **allow some quantity to vary** you are possibly intending to vary it indirectly, as in an optimization problem.

In a written exposition, or in a more careful verbal exposition, these are nuances you might want to retain, and there are accepted expressions in all technical fields, *which the experts know and use.*

In a whiteboard presentation “amongst friends”, you can use a shortcut like **variabilize** because you are physically present to give context, and to assess whether your audience understood. Outside of this informal setting, it will sound clumsy and amateurish.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that variablize/ing just sounds wrong, there is a [usually] difference between this term and parameterize/ing in the way they are used.

To parameterize is to replace constants or literals in a piece of code (procedure, routine, function, method, ...) with parameters which are fed by arguments to that piece of code.  For instance, when typing x=sin(.98), .98 is an argument.  Within the sin function this argument is stored in a variable parameter.
In this case, the argument to the sin function is parameterized.

To variablize is one step higher than parameterize.  It is to replace a piece of code with arguments and parameters.  For instance instead of saying (in some made up language):

> > EXEC ([define x; x = .98; define result; result = sin(x); return result;]);
> > the entire scrap of code is stored in a variable and fed to the routine as a argument, like so:
> > define inst LONGCHAR;
> > inst = [define x; x = .98; define result; result = sin(x); return result;]
> > EXEC (inst);
> > $$ 0.017103393
> > Now pieces of code are treated as variables and can even be manipulated as variables.

Variablize isn't that common and would be [probably] be considered incorrect in terms of referring to basic arguments and parameters.

Answer (score -1):

"Shochasticize"?  In that you are assuming that your observation (data point) represents an example of a variable with a random distribution of some type.